# How to update rails rspec nasted let attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to change attribute inside previously defined `let` to make my test works. I know it is hash in hash but none of my solutions works.

I've got several similar `let` but which looked like this

```
let(:second_data) do
  {
    'id' => second.id.to_s,
    'type' => 'account',
    'attributes' =>
     {
       'status' => 'new',
       'created_at' => second.created_at.as_json,
       'time_information' => second.credit.process.date_of_interest.as_json
     }
   }
end
```

At the end these lets are merged to one

```
let(:json_serialized_offers) do
  {
    'data' => [first_data, second_data, third_data],
    'included' => first_included + second_included + third_included
  }
end
```

Now I want to change status to `expired` in `second_data` which is nested in section `data` in `:json_serialized_offers` (as you see above).

I was trying to declere it once again, in right context, by

```
context "when status 'closed' passed " do
            let(:json_serialized_offers) do
              {
                'data' => second_data { status: 'expire' }
              }
            end
            # some logic
          end
```

But nothing changed, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a another "let" to set the status attribute.

Create a :status variable with a new `let` and change your first `let` like so:

```
let(:status) { 'new' } # <==== new let

let(:second_data) do
  {
    'id' => second.id.to_s,
    'type' => 'account',
    'attributes' =>
     {
       'status' => status # <==== set status using new variable
       'created_at' => second.created_at.as_json,
       'time_information' => second.credit.process.date_of_interest.as_json
     }
   }
end
```

Then, in the context where you need to change it, just redefine :status.

```
context "when status 'closed' passed " do
  let(:status) { 'expired' }
  it ...
end
```

This will redefine :status within this context, and will also change the status attribute in :second_data.

This strategy is great for setting deeply nested attributes, and it also makes it so that *you only have to redefine the things that changed.*